# Watermark Position Issue

Tags: php, gd, watermark

I have an issue with watermark position I want to set the position left center, How can I set dynamically here is the function of watermark

```
function ($location) {
   $watermark = imagecreatefromgif("wm.gif");
   $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
   $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
   $image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($location);
   $size = getimagesize($location);
   $pos_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 690;
   $pos_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 250;
   imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
   imagejpeg($image, $location);
   imagedestroy($image);
   imagedestroy($watermark);
}
```

Comment: When you say left-center - how far left, full?  What are the two absolute numbers in aid of?

Comment: @Orbling yes full left and center

Answer (score 1):

If you want it full left and vertically centred, then you need to change the two position calculations.

```
$pos_x = 0;
$pos_y = intval(($size[1] / 2) - ($watermark_height / 2));
```

You find half way on the source image, take off half the height of the watermark, and that'll give you the top of the watermark location.

Note that doesn't cater well for a case where the watermark is bigger than the source image.